# How to use browsermob with python-selenium behind a corporate proxy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browsermob-proxy

My test environment is under a corporate proxy ("**proxy.ptbc.std.com:2538**").I want to open a particular video on YoTube for a period of time (eg 200 seconds) and capture the har file for each visit, the process is repeated several times for a massive test. I have tried different examples found here but the firefox / chrome browsers do not connect to the internet because they are behind the proxy.

How can run "python-selenium + browsermobproxy" behind a corporate proxy and capture the har file for each instance.

Example code:

```
 from browsermobproxy import Server
    server = Server("C:\\Utility\\browsermob-proxy-2.1.4\\bin\\browsermob-proxy")
    server.start()
    proxy = server.create_proxy()

    from selenium import webdriver
    profile  = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_proxy(proxy.selenium_proxy())
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)


    proxy.new_har("google")
    driver.get("http://www.google.co.in")
    proxy.har # returns a HAR JSON blob

    server.stop()
    driver.quit()
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

According to [browsermob-proxy documentation](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy):

> Sometimes you will want to route requests through an upstream proxy
> server. In this case specify your proxy server by adding the httpProxy
> parameter to your create proxy request:
>
> ```
> [~]$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/proxy?httpProxy=yourproxyserver.com:8080
> {"port":8081}
> ```

According to [source code of browsermob-proxy API for Python](https://browsermob-proxy-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/browsermobproxy/server.html#Server)

```py
def create_proxy(self, params=None):
    """
    Gets a client class that allow to set all the proxy details that you
    may need to.

    :param dict params: Dictionary where you can specify params
    like httpProxy and httpsProxy
    """
    params = params if params is not None else {}
    client = Client(self.url[7:], params)
    return client
```

So, everything you need is to specify `params` in `create_proxy` depending on what proxy you use (http or https):

```py
from browsermobproxy import Server
from selenium import webdriver
import json

server = Server("C:\\Utility\\browsermob-proxy-2.1.4\\bin\\browsermob-proxy")
server.start()
# httpProxy or httpsProxy
proxy = server.create_proxy(params={'httpProxy': 'proxy.ptbc.std.com:2538'})
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_proxy(proxy.selenium_proxy())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

proxy.new_har("google")
driver.get("http://www.google.co.in")
result = json.dumps(proxy.har, ensure_ascii=False)
print(result)

server.stop()
driver.quit()
```